# Regular expression for numbers beginning with 0300, 0500, 0800, 0808

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one tell me regular expression that no. should start with:

- 0300
- 0500
- 0800
- 0808

I am using this but it is not working

```
(0800|0300)\d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
0[358]0[08]\d*
```

If you are looking for only one such number on each line in a file, you can use this:

```
^0[358]0[08]\d*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0[358][08]\d*
```

should work.  What doesn't work for you?

Comment: "*…that no. should start with*" so probably needs a `^`. ;-)

Comment: Yes, of course, and *start with* means "start with". :-)